# Как передать саму функцию в bind JavaScript

Tags: javascript, переменные, параметры, bind

Всем привет!
Как и все, кто волею судьбы и руководства изучает JavaScript, столкнулся с передачей параметров в `addEventListener`.
Проблема легко решается с помощью `.bind`:

```
handler = function(contextParameter){
console.log(contextParameter);
}
var f = handler.bind(this, context);
parentDiv.addEventListener('click', f('Hello Wolrd!'));
```

Однако возникает другая проблема, когда создаёшь в цикле несколько объектов и хочешь удалить этот Listener.
Не могу сослаться внутри handler на саму функцию внутри `removeEventListener`, чтобы удалить её на(...)конец.
По-быстрому придумал костыли - заношу созданные переменные в массив `a_f`, и в .bind передаю текущий `i`
Далее, удаляю таким макаром:
`o_parentToPass.removeEventListener('click', a_f[v_na]);`
Где `v_na` - параметр, передаваемый в handler, соответствующий `i`
Помогите, плиз, как сделать всё красиво! Перелистал уже всю мозилу и w3, ничего подходящего не могу найти(((
Как мне передать саму переменную `f` внутри `f = handler.bind(this, o_context, i);`
По подобию: 

`f = handler.bind(this, o_context, this);`

`Или f = handler.bind(this, o_context, f);`

Эти два варианта сверху не работают (

Вот код:

```
var a_f = [];
var handler = function(o_parentToPass, v_na){
if(o_parentToPass.classList.contains('test-rotate')){
    o_parentToPass.classList.remove('test-rotate');
}else{
    o_parentToPass.classList.add('test-rotate');
}
o_parentToPass.removeEventListener('click', a_f[v_na]);
console.log(v_na);
}

var f_createDiv = function(){
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var o_parent = document.createElement('div');
    o_parent.classList.add('parent');
    var o_picture = document.createElement('div');
    o_picture.classList.add('child', 'picture');
    var o_cover = document.createElement('div');
    o_cover.classList.add('child', 'cover', 'rotate-cover');
    var vs_text = document.createElement('p');
    vs_text.innerHTML = i;
    o_parent.appendChild(o_picture);
    o_parent.appendChild(o_cover);
    o_parent.appendChild(vs_text);

    var o_context = o_parent;
    var f = handler.bind(this, o_context, i);
    a_f.push(f);

    o_parent.addEventListener('click', f);
    document.body.appendChild(o_parent);
}
}
```

Вариант с

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
const node = ...;
const handler = function() {
    // ...
    node.removeEventListener("click", handler);
}
node.addEventListener("click", handler);
}
```

Не совсем подходит. Т.к. handler в моём случае - внешний. Его нельзя разместить внутри цикла.

Короче - лучший вариант "прикрутить" к вызываемому методу добавление listener с помощью `calm` передавать ноду через `bind` и добавлять listener уже в самом методе.

Comment: Ребят, по замыканиям - всё круто. Однако как им пользоваться, когда функция заимствована и не допускается разместить её в своём цикле?

Comment: При указании имени *уже объявленной функции*, Вы не "размещаете" ее, а передаете по ссылке (by reference). Сама же функция - где объявлена, там и остается. Новые функции создаются только при использовании функционального выражения (function expression)... и да, это действительно очень плохая практика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Достаточно сделать так:

```
<element>.addEventListener(<eventName>, { handleEvent: <handlerFunction> });
```

, без всякого излишнего секса с `bind()` или замыканием функции.

---

**Пояснение:**
Аргументом в `addEventListener` можно передавать не только функцию, но и объект соответствующий интерфейсу [**`EventListener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventListener), насовав все необходимые Вам параметры в его (объекта) поля. Внутри функции-листенера, этот объект будет доступен через `this`.

---

---

**Пример:**
Сниппет ниже, демонстрирует создание в цикле элементов, реагирующих на клик увеличением их значения на рандомную величину от 1 до 25 включительно.  Как только значение достигает 50, слушатель события удаляется.
Чтобы было нагляднее, каждый добавляемый объект слушателя содержит *три* поля:

- `handleEvent` - непосредственно обработчик события. В данном случае, это обычная именованная функция из глобальной области видимости;
- `el` - элемент, владеющий слушателем события *(можно не передавать, так как в обработчике доступно свойство `target` аргумента `Event`. То есть, вместо `this.el` можно юзать `evt.target`)*;
- `rndIncr` - референс функции, генерирующей случайную величину инкремента.

```js
for (let elem, evtHandler, i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  elem = document.createElement('span'); 
  elem.classList.add('test'); 
  elem.textContent = '0'; 
  evtHandler = {
    el: elem, 
    rndIncr: rndIncrement,
    handleEvent: clickHandler 
  }; 
  elem.addEventListener('click', evtHandler); 
  document.body.appendChild(elem); 
}

function clickHandler(evt) {
  let i = this.rndIncr(), 
      newVal = +this.el.textContent + i; 
  console.clear(); 
  console.log('Случайный инкремент: ' + i); 
  this.el.textContent = String(newVal);
  if (newVal >= 50) {
    this.el.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 1px #ccc'; 
    this.el.removeEventListener('click', this); 
  }
}

function rndIncrement() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1; 
}
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block; 
  margin: 5px; 
  width: 50px; line-height: 50px; 
  text-align: center; 
  user-select: none; 
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 #0004; 
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out; 
}
```

**Почему это важно, и чем это (имхо) лучше:**

Во-первых, такой "объектный" подход читабельнее по коду:
*<sup>«вот объект с такими-то полями, и вот мы его передаем»</sup>*
вместо варианта ф. выражений:
*<sup>«вот функция, которая создает замыкание, в котором объявлены переменные, которые передаются вложенной функции <del>, в доме который построил Джек</del>»</sup>*
То есть, решение типа "есть же callback hell, так давайте еще мини function expression hell запилим" - скажем так, сомнительное... Плюс, не будем забывать что вызовы в JavaScript *дорогие*.

Во-вторых, способ достаточно универсален: он позволяет инкапсулировать обработчики внутри любого объекта, включая объекты являющиеся экземплярами класса. То есть, не обязательно передавать именно литерал объекта - можно использовать фабрику, или конструктор, или добавить поле обработчика в уже созданный экземпляр. Когда в коде активно используются объекты, это будет удобно.

В-третьих, такой подход "более стандартный", что ли... В том смысле, что метод `addEventListener` явно предполагает использование объектов во втором аргументе - тогда как использование `bind()` или вложенных функций, *в данном контексте*, смахивает на костыль.

Comment: Ты ЖЖЁШЬ!!!!! Как таким умным стал??? ))))))))))))

Comment: Спасибо, большое! )))) Уже использую передачу объектов.

Comment: @O.O, источник ответа тут скорее не ум, а внимательное чтение MDN :) Пожалуйста, я рад, что эта инфа помогла!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант `f = handler.bind(this, o_context, f)` не работает, потому что сначала выполняется правая часть выражения. А значит в `bind` передается старое значение `f` (или `undefined` на первой итерации цикла).

Мой вариант для вашего случая, функция `handler` отдельно от основного кода, и вы можете удалять обработчик, когда захотите. Надеюсь код достаточно простой для понимания :)

```js
function handler(element, parameter, getEventHandler) {
  element.innerHTML += parameter;
  if (true) // ваше условие
    element.removeEventListener('click', getEventHandler());
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = i;
  
  (function () {
    var bindedHandler;
    var getBindedHandler = function () { return bindedHandler; }
    bindedHandler = handler.bind(this, div, '-clicked-' + i, getBindedHandler);
    div.addEventListener('click', bindedHandler);
  })();
  
  document.body.append(div);
}
```

Если задача требудет выполнения обработчика только 1 раз, можно испольвазть третий аргумент `addEventListener`. Мы указываем браузеру, что обработчик должен вызваться только 1 раз, а потом браузер сам удалит его:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = i;
  
  div.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.innerHTML += '-clicked';
  }, { once: true });
  
  document.body.append(div);
}
```

Comment: arguments.callee запрещено в строгом режиме

Comment: Первый вариант не подходит, потому что функция заимствуется и очень большая, чтобы размещать её в теле Listener. Кроме того есть ветвь с условиями когда удалять или не удалять Listener. Второй вариант не подходит по причине того, что неизвестно заранее сколько раз должен выполниться Listener. Цель кода - реализация головоломки "Сейф" братьев пилотов на html css js https://i.ytimg.com/vi/THGQxkKqCCg/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @O.O я добавил новый вариант, надеюсь вам подойдет

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - через замыкание. Просто создаем переменную и на нее ссылаемся:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    const node = ...;
    const handler = function() {
        // ...
        node.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    }
    node.addEventListener("click", handler);
}
```

Если вы пишите для браузеров которые не поддерживают let и const - то можно использовать еще одно замыкание чтобы разделить области видимости:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) 
    !function(){
        var node = ...;
        var handler = function() {
            // ...
            node.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        }
        node.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }();
```

Здесь я использовал IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) - немедленно вызываемое функциональное выражение. Этот трюк позволяет создать на каждой итерации цикла новые переменные node и handler, без него бы метод removeEventListener всегда отписывал последний обработчик события а не текущий.

Если прошлый пример кажется слишком магическим - вот то же самое, но без IIFE:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
    step(i);

function step(i) {
    var node = ...;
    var handler = function() {
        // ...
        node.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    }
    node.addEventListener("click", handler);        
}
```

Comment: Ok. Вариант с замыканием и константами очень красивый. Однако - как его применить, если используется заимствованная функция, которую нельзя размещать внутри цикла???

Comment: @O.O размещайте ее снаружи, а внутри цикла - вызывайте